# Find unique elements in a column in Apache Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset as follows

Id| interests
1| riding, reading, cooking
2| riding, running
3| travelling, cooking

Is it possible to retrieve a summary of interests like

riding,  2
reading, 1
cooking, 2
running, 1
travelling, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below.

```
val firstRDD = sc.textFile("/path_to_file/file.txt").map(line =>line.split("\\|")(1))

val resultRDD=firstRDD.flatMap(line => line.split(",")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

resultRDD.collect
```

Here is the output from scala shell

```
res23: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((reading,1), (cooking,2), (travelling,1), (running,1), (riding,2))
```